# Curves: uniqueness of change of parameter

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, geometry, differential-geometry, function-and-relation-composition

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ a fixed natural number and $I_\varphi\subset\mathbb{R}$ a fixed compact interval. Consider the space of all $\cal{C}^1$ functions $\varphi:I_\varphi\to \mathbb{R}^n$. Define an equivalence relation as $\varphi \cal{R} \phi$ iff there exists a function $\lambda:I_\varphi\to \phi$ that is bijective, $\lambda \in \cal{C}^1(I_\varphi), \lambda^{-1} \in \cal{C}^1(I_\phi)$ and $\varphi = \phi \circ \lambda$. This application $\lambda$ is called change of parameter.

Is the change of parameter between $\phi$ and $\varphi$ unique? The above are the definitions I was given, but I suppose we are not considering 'degenerated curves', that is, Im $\varphi$ is not a single point.

My guess is that there is uniqueness, but I couldn't conclude. My attemp:
$$
\varphi \circ \lambda_1 = \varphi \circ \lambda_2 \implies \varphi \circ \lambda_1 \circ \lambda_2^{-1} = \varphi
$$

But how does this imply that $\lambda_1 \circ \lambda_2^{-1} = Id$?

Comment: There’s an evident typo in the definition of $\lambda$. There is certainly no uniqueness if $\varphi$ is constant on a subinterval.

Comment: @TedShifrin The intention is to define curves as classes of equivalence, and oriented curves as classes of equivalence with the equivalence relation $\cal{R}_2$: $\varphi \cal{R}_2 \phi$ iff $\varphi \cal{R}\phi$ and the change of parameter is strictly increasing. Is being nonlocal a property of $\varphi$ that should be added?

Comment: Even strictly increasing won’t fix anything if the map is constant on an interval. There are infinitely many diffeomorphisms of one closed interval to another with predetermined derivatives at the endpoints.

Comment: @TedShifrin So 'being nonlocally constant' is a property that should be imposed on $\varphi$? Or I should just be aware that I cannot have uniqueness of the change of parameter due to the possibility of the paramtrization being nonlocal? If I impose that $\varphi$ is nonlocal, is the uniqueness of the change of parameter $\lambda$ true?

Comment: I do not know what nonlocal means.

Comment: @TedShifrin I edited, I meant nonlocally constant, in the sense that there is no open set where the restriction of $\varphi$ is constant.